# Cannot Run Bitlocker Despite Already Having Flash Disk

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

The bitlocker enscryption key cannot be obtained verify that the trusted platform module is enabled and ownership...

My best guess of what's wrong is that my computer cannot 
"see" the flash disk until the windows is on. And windows can't be on until the bitlocker is open.

I think there's something on BIOS I should turn on.

But what?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went to BIOS there is an option of fast boot. It seems that fast boot means the computer doesn't have access to USB until operating system kicks in.

I tweaked the fast boot option so that it can access USB before operating system. Problem solved.